# How to write following code in lambda expression or linq?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I just want to know that how to write following code in lambda expression or linq. Please answer if you know.

```
Process[] runingProcess = Process.GetProcesses();
ManagementObjectCollection moReturn;
ManagementObjectSearcher moSearch;

void func()
{                                                                          
    moSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Product");  
    moReturn = moSearch.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in moReturn)
    {
        foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(mo["Name"].ToString()))
        {
            process.Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any code fragment which you had tried on the same yet?

Comment: Yes fujiFX .var pro = Process.GetProcesses().Where(i => (i.ProcessName != "lmc");
foreach (var prc in pro)
                {
                    prc.Kill();
                }

Comment: Do you have a sample of the code where you would be calling `func` from? A lambda express simply does away with the function name and turns it into an anonymous function. So instead of calling `myobj.Method(func);` you would call `myobj.Method(()=> { /* your function body here... */ });`

Comment: I just expect like this @fujiFX.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is LINQ equivalent for iterating part:

```
moReturn.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().ToList().ForEach(mo => Process.GetProcessesByName(mo["Name"].ToString()).ToList().ForEach(proc => proc.Kill()));
```

Edit : This answer is semantically equivalent to the iteration in the OP question, but it doesn't gain anything. See other upvoted answers which is more proper by using `SelectMany` to flatten the `Processes` instead of `ForEach`.

Comment: Thank you @hendry, but its showing error like managemant object collection does not contain definition for Tolist

Comment: @chinnathambir my bad, should've cast it first. Please see edited answer.

Comment: It may look like LINQ, and smell like LINQ, but using `.ToList().ForEach()...` is not proper LINQ.

Comment: @Maarten I think you are right. What are your opinion for ClearLogic's answer?

Comment: @Hendry I think the `.ToList()` is acceptable since it is at the end of the query, but the usage of `.ForEach(...)` is not something I would do. It doesn't gain anything, and if you make it a habit it can seriously make it difficult to follow what is happening. And not to mention the garbled stacktraces.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike the other answers, I consider using `.ToList()` and `.ForEach(...)` to be the opposite of LINQ. Once you use those keywords, your LINQ query ends. Especially `.ForEach()`, since the purpose of `.ForEach(...)` is to [cause a side-effect](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/), and LINQ is for querying.

My version would be:

```
// Query for processes to kill
var data = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Product")
    .Get()
    .Cast<ManagementObject>()
    .SelectMany(mo => Process.GetProcessesByName(mo["Name"].ToString()));

// Kill the processes
foreach (var item in data) {
    item.Kill();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **SelectMany** to flatten processes.

```
    var moSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Product");  
    var moReturn = moSearch.Get();
    var processes = moReturn.Cast<ManagementObject>()
                            .SelectMany (mo => Process.GetProcessesByName(mo["Name"].ToString()))
                            .ToList();

        processes.ForEach(p=> p.Kill() );
```

or in Query syntax

```
    var moSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Product");  
    var moReturn = moSearch.Get();
    var processes = (from mo in moReturn.Cast<ManagementObject>()
                     from prc in Process.GetProcessesByName(mo["Name"].ToString())
                     select prc).ToList();

        processes.ForEach(p=> p.Kill() );
```